# Can a TeamCity Linux build agent run Perl tests with TAP output?

Tags: linux, perl, continuous-integration, teamcity, tap

I've been able to add a Linux machine as build agent in TeamCity without too much hassle, but it's having some trouble running my Perl test suite.  When I add this as a build step:

```
prove -j4 --formatter TAP::Formatter::TeamCity
```

I get the following **error :**

> Missing '...' at end of YAMLish at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.0/TAP/Parser  /YAMLish/Reader.pm line 49,  line 2.
>   Process exited with code 25
>   Step Run test scripts (Command Line) failed

I actually get that whether I pass a `--formatter` value or not.  When I run this from the local command line of the same machine, it runs just fine.  That area in `Reader.pm` looks like this:

```
# The terminator is mandatory otherwise we'd consume a line from the
# iterator that doesn't belong to us. If we want to remove this
# restriction we'll have to implement look-ahead in the iterators.
# Which might not be a bad idea.
my $dots = $self->_peek;
die "Missing '...' at end of YAMLish"  #Line 49
  unless defined $dots
      and $dots =~ $IS_END_YAML;
```

I tried changing that `die` to a `warn` and sure enough it started ingesting all the console output and it of course choked before too long.

`uname -r` on the Linux box yields `3.5.0-45-generic #68-precise1-Ubuntu`.

Anyone know any ways around this?